# .NET Core console app. Nuget package added, but "using" not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
>dotnet --version
3.1.301
```

I just created a basic console app with:

```
dotnet add console
```

Now I open the folder in VS Code, and in the Terminal I do

```
dotnet add package PrestaSharp
```

My csproj looks like this now:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="PrestaSharp" Version="1.2.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="108.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

However, my Program.cs has a compilation error "type or namespace 'PrestaSharp' could not be found":

```
using System;
using PrestaSharp;

namespace USBPrintTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                

        }
    }
}
```

even after `dotnet build` I get the error

Comment: Have you tried running a build on the solution? Sometimes VS doesn't pick up on all dependencies until you do that. In any case, you shouldn't be using .net core 3.1 anymore -- it is no longer supported and is at end-of-life. You should be using .net 6 or .net 7.https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: ````dotnet build```` did not solve the issue :( I need this for an existing app That's built with netcore 3.1; it's not a New project

Comment: are you sure you are using the full namespace for the project?

Comment: wow! I feel so dumbs now.. Indeed it was ````using Bukimedia.PrestaSharp;```` Lesson learned! Is there any way to find the full Namespace?

Comment: Just add something from the lib in your code and have intellisense add the using?

Answer (score 0):

It seems PrestaSharp v1.2.9 can run on .NETFramework 4.5.2 or a framework that implements .NETStandard 2.0.

You are running your app on [netcoreapp3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#latest-versions) which implements .NET Standard 2.1.